# JsonConvert DeserializeObject error in c#

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following model

```
public class UserSettings
{
    public bool SendEmailAlertsForNewArticlesOrReports { get; set; }
    public bool ShowNotificationsInCubeBrowserForArticlesAndReports { get; set; }
}
```

I serialize it like this

```
string sUserSettings = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userSettings);
```

It stores this in the backend

```
"{\"SendEmailAlertsForNewArticlesOrReports\":false,\"ShowNotificationsInCubeBrowserForArticlesAndReports\":true}"
```

When I am trying to deserialize it like this

```
UserSettings userSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSettings>(result);
```

The value of result is

```
"{\"SendEmailAlertsForNewArticlesOrReports\":false,\"ShowNotificationsInCubeBrowserForArticlesAndReports\":true}"
```

I get this error

> Could not cast or convert from System.String to RystadEnergy.Web.Models.Rystad.UserSettings

Anyone knows what am I missing?

Comment: What is the exact value of `result` (please check in the `Immediate Window`)?

Comment: Maybe you have an "extra" Serialization. Check variable *result* **before** DeserializeObject. It is possible that your string start with "" (a couple of double quotes)

Comment: Yeah it was a double serialization issue. Data comes from api and I haven't written that so that is why. Solved my issue by trimming the result. :)

Comment: Great! Recommendation: try to avoid double serialization instead to trimming the result.