# Why does this return an escaped string of JSON?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I have this controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(FormDataCollection formData)
{
    return this.Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formData));
}
```

The problem is I get a string of JSON with escaped strings within like the following:

```
"[{\"Key\":\"input01\",\"Value\":\"hello world\"},{\"Key\":\"input02\",\"Value\":\"c:\\\\XXX\\\\XXX\\\\XXX\\\\XXX\\\\XXX.dwg\"},{\"Key\":\"input03\",\"Value\":\"junk\"}]"
```

How do I return plain JSON?

Comment: That's a valid string representation of your object. If you do `JSON.parse()` on that string it works just fine. If you dont want it serialized, then just `return this.Ok(formData)`

Comment: check comments on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768814/jsonconvert-deserializeobject-error-in-c-sharp#comment88545372_50768814

Comment: @tymeJV - I can't believe I overlooked that. If you want, create an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a valid string representation of your object. If you do JSON.parse() on that string it works just fine. If you dont want it serialized, then just return the actual object:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(FormDataCollection formData)
{
    return this.Ok(formData);
}
```

Comment: this throws system-outofmemoryexception-exception error in case data is large.